# Android Studio: execution failed for task : app:compileDebugAidl FAILED

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I installed Android Studio 1.2.1.1, with Gradle version 2.2.1, and Android plugin version 1.2.3. I tried to create a simple hello world project, and it give me a build failure of :app:compileDebugAidl FAILED. Am i missing something or have some incompatible issue with version, as this should be a simple application. Thanks for any help.

This is the compilation errors I am getting:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> aidl is missing
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: you should try restarting first

Comment: No, it got to be something else.. I already restart PC and it is same problem.

Comment: If you clean project and finished without errors, I think you should check Gradle config build:
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Answer (score 51):

I had the same problem.

right click on app -> Open module settings. Set in this menu the 'Build Tools Version' to version 22.0.1.

After setting this I was able to build the project successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. For clarification, is this a bug that was shipped with Android Studio or is this something potentially wrong with my setup?

Comment: Android Studio is really annoying because of it's bugs.

Comment: I think it is because you accidentally installed the Android SDK Build-tools 23 rc2 in the Android SDK manager. So it is not an Android Studio specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem and resolved by changing the Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Project-level settings from 'Use local gradle distribution' to 'Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)'.

Hope it helps.

Comment: FYI : As of version 1.2.1.1 You can find this setting under File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle

Answer (score 3):

goto File->settings->build->gradle and select Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)

Comment: I forgot to mention I had to remove SDK 23.X rc it was causing an issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by updating Android SDK build Tools.

> SDK Manager > Tool > Android SDK build Tool > Install> Restart

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the source of the error is not very clear.  I had attempted to refactor a package, but one of my classes had the old package name, making the compilation fail.  I found the error by searching my path for the error generated in the Gradle console.  I had the old package name in my project and I changed it myself.  Then my APK compiled just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Version Compatibility
Post 1.0 Compatibility
      Starting with Android Studio 1.0 and the Gradle plugin for Android 1.0, compatibility is a critical requirement.
    While we are still looking at finalizing our policy you should at least expect:

Studio 1.x works with Gradle Plugin 1.y

```
Newer versions of the Gradle plugin may require newer versions of Studio to enable the new features in the IDE, but the project should open in older versions of Studio, and build from there (since Gradle does the build). We will be very careful about this.
 We will determine later our compatibility story between Studio 2.x and Gradle Plugin 1.x and between Studio 1.x and Gradle Plugin 2.x
We will make every effort to keep compatibility where possible, and to provide good Quick Assist to help with migration where applicable.
```

Gradle plugin 1.0.0 - 1.1.3 works with Gradle 2.2.1 - 2.3.

```
It does not work with Gradle 2.4+
```

Gradle plugin 1.2+ works with Gradle [2.2.1, 3.0[

```
Newer versions of the Plugin may require a newer version of Gradle to benefit from advanced features.

However the current 1.2+ should work with [2.2.1, 3.0[
(We cannot guaranteed compatibility with 3.x as it may introduce breaking changes: Gradle 1.x -> 2.0 introduced Groovy breaking changes)


Android Studio      Android Gradle Plugin      Gradle

1.0.0+               1.0.0 - 1.1.3           2.2.1 - 2.3
1.0.0+               1.2+                    2.2.1+
```

Post 1.0 DSL compatibility

The DSL changed a lot before 1.0, but it should be stable now.

If/When we need to change things we will have long deprecation periods, likely longer than 6 months, possibly 12 months.
Preview Compatibility
This table indicate compatibility for pre-1.0 components.

All this breaking changes happened because we tweaked the model exchanged between the IDE and Gradle a lot. All this work was to ensure stability after 1.0.

for more information go to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the whole app, try running a particular activity only which contains the `<intent-filter>` After that try running the whole app.