# could not build app Error:Execution failed for task ':app:package "packageName" Debug'. > value (73836) > 0x0000ffff

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Could not build app.

Build failed :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:package "packageName" Debug'.> value (73836) > 0x0000ffff
```

the project is build succesfuly ,but adding a line of code(Log.i())
receive failed build message,after restarting (invalidate caches)works as expected

gradle-wrapper.properites

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip
```

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    multiDexEnabled true

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/adobeMobileLibrary.jar')
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.4'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
}
```

Comment: Problem is not in code, I could find any solution ,everytime I restart (invalidating caches) it starts working and this problem appears from time to time adding some simple  code

Comment: I'm dealing with it too, same solution. Which Android Studio version do you use?

Comment: Perhaps you have to configure, clearly, your Build Tools Version, see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518750/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-failed

Comment: @ Franklin Hirata  @ Eliran Tutia   I have update the question and android studio version is 2.1.1

Comment: @I.S.S.J I had version 1.4.1 and then I updated to 2.1.1. Now everything is ok. Maybe try to reinstall your Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

androidstudio1.5 gradle 2.2.0-alpha,occurs to me like this question; fix gradle to 1.5.0;then it solved

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer but the only thing that seems to work for me is to kill the java process and hit `Run` again.